# CUPS job-name document-name

Tags: cups, lpd

I have CUPS 1.6.3.22 on Centos7
and when I print from AIX6.1 machine the job gets no name-title

so it shows "Untitled" on the Jobs web page in the column "Name".

And I want no banner page.
I know that with the lpr command and a banner, the job title gets its correct value.

I send the job via lp

```
lp -c -d$PROFILES$.PRINTER -onobanner -n$PROFILES$.CONC_COPIES -t"$PROFILES$.TITLE" $PROFILES$.FILENAME
```

The job comes in to my cups-server via cups-lpd I think.
The log shows:

```
D [05/Feb/2016:13:07:26 +0100] [Job 3507] argv[0]="16_PRN"
D [05/Feb/2016:13:07:26 +0100] [Job 3507] argv[1]="3507"
D [05/Feb/2016:13:07:26 +0100] [Job 3507] argv[2]="root"
D [05/Feb/2016:13:07:26 +0100] [Job 3507] argv[3]="Untitled"
D [05/Feb/2016:13:07:26 +0100] [Job 3507] argv[4]="1"
D [05/Feb/2016:13:07:26 +0100] [Job 3507] argv[5]="document-name=ThisIsTest job-originating-host-name=myaix.machine.com job-uuid=urn:uuid:47ccd6c0-e2ff-3f0d-598e-466927f26e3b time-at-creation=1454674046 time-at-processing=1454674046"
```

so as you can see the job-name(argv[3]) is "Untitled" but in the options(argv[5]) there we have "document-name=ThisIsTest"

The question is:

How to make Cups-LPD work like it is described in rfc2911 about IPP:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2911#section-4.3.5

I mean that "...the printer SHOULD generate the value of the Job's
'job-name' attribute from ...the 'document-name' operation attribute"

Answer (score 2):

I would go into the `/etc/cups/cupsd.config` page
and change the commented following to:

```
<Policy default>
  # Job/subscription privacy...
# JobPrivateAccess default
# JobPrivateValues default
  JobPrivateAccess all
  JobPrivateValues none
```

Comment: 6 years too late for the OP but perfect timing for me looking at a similar issue today. In my case was trying to get the job names to display in the CUPS web UI for all users so they could reprint specific jobs from the completed queue - JobPrivateValues none did the trick for me. Thanks for a useful first contribution.