# CUPS - Display filename in the Joblist

Tags: filenames, cups

Is there an option to display the printed filename in the CUPS job list? From the job list, based on the filename user would select the files to be reprinted. Earlier we were able to achieve this when the jobs were running in Windows system. But in Cups it just displays the job ID not the job name. As an alternative I have tried to connect to a Windows shared printer but to it also the Document name is just sent as "Print Document".

Any help or advise would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer from the below post and it worked

[CUPS job-name document-name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260118/cups-job-name-document-name?rq=1)

Comment and edit the JobPrivateValues in cupsd.conf as below

```
<Policy default>
  # Job/subscription privacy...
# JobPrivateAccess default
# JobPrivateValues default
  JobPrivateAccess all
  JobPrivateValues none
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [link-only answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) are discouraged, as the link may become invalid or the linked content change. Please edit your answer to include at least a summary of the linked explanation.